# How to read json file which has double quotes using python?

Tags: python, json

I have been trying to parse a JSON string that has double quotes, but always get the error.

I have looked at many StackOverflow links to solve the issue, but none of them worked.

## How to read the json file (not string) which has double quotes and backslashes?

```py
import json

#===== ignore this part, this is just file I want to read using json
s = r"""
{"name" : "Help",
    "snippet" : [
                    "cd \"C:\\Users\\a126291\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\nbextensions\\snippets_menu\\snippets_submenus_python\"",
                    "explorer.exe \"https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas\""
                ]
            }

"""

with open('mydata.json','w') as fo:
    fo.write(s)

#============== now starts the question
with open('mydata.json') as fh:
    j = json.load(fh)
    
print(j)
```

I get following error:
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 5 column 74 (char 241)

Comment: This is a comment.

Comment: Your JSON array is missing closing ]

Answer (score 1):

You're also missing a closing bracket `]` on snippet's value. However, if you fix that, you can just make it a raw string by leading with an `r`

```
import json

json_str = r"""
{"name" : "Help",
    "snippet" : [
                    "cd \"C:\\Downloads\" "]

}
"""

data = json.loads(json_str)
print(data['snippet'])
# ['cd "C:\\Downloads" ']
```

This resolves your issue. The problem is that without the `r` prefix, the escaped characters are handled when assigning to `json_str`, which means they are no longer there when you call `json.loads`.

Comment: I loaded the data from `data.json`, so I can not use r"my string", is there a way doing without using r-string?